# Open Image Thumbnail in a new page, while clicking on the link

Tags: thumbnails

I am trying to open the thumbnail image on a new page using WordPress. For example. I have all the detail of a single post on a page and if someone clicks on the link given on a single page it opens the thumbnail on another page as a child theme.

**Single Page Code "single.php"**

```
<a href="WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE" ); ?>">link to Another Page </a>
```

**Theme of Another Page with name single-thumnail.php**

```
<?php 
/***
Template Name: Advertisement
***/

get_header(); ?>

<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass post slug in the query string with your new page URL.

`single-thumnail.php?post=slug`

Fetched thumb image by post id and show.

Comment: can you please give an example in a code format?

Comment: I am really confused here. I am working on [Jobs's Website](https://fiajobs.com). Please let me know if you can explain it a little bit more. I am going to open my image in a separate HTML tab